# C standard conforming way to do struct alignment

Tags: c

Is there a C standard conforming way to do struct alignment?

I know that one could put the biggest elements first but I am in a situation where I am about to implement a protocol.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "C"?

Comment: Like most things, it has already been answered on SO.  Google "c struct serialization  site:stackoverflow.com" and see a plethora of answers that answer your meta question of "How do I send a struct across a wire"

Comment: @wiix Comments on any C standard are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

No, not in general.

You absolutely cannot change the order of elements in a structure, they have to be in the exact order as declared.

But you also cannot know in advance what some future processor will prefer, in terms of alignment.

Protocols (which are "external" representations) should *never* involve directly copying to/from a `struct` in memory; instead you must serialize/deserialize each struct member on its own.

Comment: Isn't there any pragma directive?

Answer (score 1):

For implementing a protocol, it is best to serialize the values as needed and deserialize them as well.

This retains compatibilty across architectures with varying data field sizes, alignment requirements and endianness.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify alignment in C11 with the `_Alignas` keyword (see also `stdalign.h`). You can look it up in the [draft of the C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) that is freely available.

Comment: `_Alignas` provides stricter alignment (e.g., changing a one-byte aligned type to four-byte aligned). It will not provide the byte-packed alignment needed for serializing.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on some kind of directive is probably not a good idea. I would not do it. Custom serializers/deserializers are the standard here.

I suggest writing a simple parser that would process a `struct` declaration and prepare a set of serialize/deserialize functions. If it is a simple plain old data structure, the parser and code generator will be very simple and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you plan to do something like a union overlay to encode / decode the protocol. This is a bad idea. It is much better to do a proper serialise / deserialise, field by field.
This is much more portable.